# How to archive, not discard, old data in Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, archive

I'm currently assessing Apache Kafka for use in our technology stack.  One thing which may become critical is a contractual or legal requirement to be able to audit the system's behaviour, retaining this audit information for as much as a year.

Given the volume of data we process we will, most likely, need to cold-store this rather than simply partitioning the data and setting a long retention period.  Cold-store here means storing in Amazon S3 or multiple locally held TB HDDs.

*We could of course set up a logger against every topic. Yes.*

But this feels like it should be a *solved problem* to which I just can't find a documented solution.

What's the best way of archiving old data from Apache Kafka rather than simply discarding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [S3 sink connector](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-to-amazon-s3-exactly-once) to stream the data to S3, and then set the retention period on your topics as required to age-out the data.

Comment: Thanks,  Just saw your article on Confluent. Its more detailed. Just adding here from further reading by others.  https://www.confluent.io/blog/no-more-silos-how-to-integrate-your-databases-with-apache-kafka-and-cdc/